# Map through an array that creates a horizontal table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to map through an array and dynamically create a horizontal table, much like the image below here.[image]

I am mapping through an array like so,

```
 const glanceGames = this.state.gameData.map(game => {
        return <GameTable
            key={game.id}
            home_team_name={game.home_name_abbrev}
            away_team_name={game.away_name_abbrev}
            home_score={game.linescore.r.home}
            away_score={game.linescore.r.away}
            status={game.status.status}
        />
    })
```

and then using that data to populate the following component.

```
const GameTable = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
           <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>{props.status}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{props.home_team_name}</td>
                    <td>{props.home_score}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{props.away_team_name}</td>
                    <td>{props.away_score}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
)
```

}

However, the output is a vertical table rather than a horizontal one. I feel like this should be easy, yet I keep running into issues. Anu suggestions would be helpful! I am using React.

Comment: `thead` and `tbody` should be wrapped inside a `table` instead of `div`

Comment: the output of that results in each game taking up the width of the view in a list format, I'd like to have all games on one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is nothing to do with react, we can just do it with css:

```
...

render(){
  <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
    {glanceGames}
  </div>
}
```